# Unwind segue not being triggered

Tags: ios, ios6, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard that has a starting view controller that presents other modal view controllers.

Say view controller A is the startingViewController, and view controller B is the modally presented view controller.

How can I trigger the unwind segue from B back to A, from ViewController A ( not just from a button located on ViewController B)?

The button works to perform the unwind segue , but when I try to perform it programmatically using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ReturnToStart" sender:self]
```

an error occurs:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<StartViewController: 0x1ed4b9b0>) has no segue with identifier 'ReturnToStart''
```

What I don't understand is that the unwind segue is working fine when I press a button on the modal view controller, but the segue just can't be found when I attempt to trigger it from another ViewController (The identifier is correct in storyboard).

Is there any way of accessing all of the segues from my startingViewController or is my structure fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segue "belongs" to the source `View Controller`, so that's why you get that error message. Segues are intended to be called from the source view controller.

If you want to dismiss viewControllerB from A, don't use a segue, just use:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought that somehow all segues can be accessed by all view controllers contained in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks. Found out that you can only use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method if you have connected your view controllers on the Storyboard. If you instantiated the view programmatically you need to use this.