# unwind segue programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I cant seem to be able to do this correctly so I'll try to explain the best I can. I have view controller 1 and then within view controller one I then create another view to basically show as thought is hovering over the current view(lets call it 2). That view now has a button and i need to go back to view 0 which is where it all started. so I created a segue and then i try to perform the segue but in not getting anywhere.
so here is how i attempted to accomplish this .
In view 1 i have this

```
// this is in the nearmeView controller
-(void)BackToStart{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwind" sender:self];
//dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

 }
```

in the popped up view i have this.

```
 NearMeViewController * goBackToBeggining = [[NearMeViewController alloc]init];
    [goBackToBeggining BackToStart];
```

however i get an error that says this?

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<NearMeViewController: 0x19af9600>) has no segue with identifier 'unwind''
```

now i know is must be me not instatiating the view correctly how should i do this? what I'm i missing?
I read this post but it didn't help much any ideas?
[Unwind segue not being triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405937/unwind-segue-not-being-triggered)

Comment: you can trigger an unwind segue directly from the button. You don't instantiate a new view controller to trigger it. Perhaps have a look here http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues

Comment: Paulw this does not really answer my question. I will put a test project together and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unwind segues are tricky. For this case, however, you don't even need one; just have your `BackToStart` call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`. However, if you're using storyboards and need to use an unwind segue, you have to add an `IBAction` method to the target view controller, and it has to take a `UIStoryboardSegue` argument:

```
- (IBAction)comeToPapa:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    // ... whatever
}
```

Then, in your child view controller's storyboard scene, ctrl+drag from whatever triggers the unwind and drag it up to the child view controller's green Exit icon in the scene header. This will pop up a list of available unwind segues; select the one you just created in the parent view controller.

[Here's what Apple says about it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)

Comment: I tried to use the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` and litterally nothing happens.

Comment: you were right I'm an idiot thanks for the response. I figured out my issue.